# Need resources for Statistical Natural Language Processing

Tags: java, statistics, nlp

I'm writing a program in Java that needs to parse natural language. I need this to be done using probability and statistics. Are there any resources that can easily explain Statistical Natural Language Processing techniques?

Answer (score 8):

A commonly cited "introductory" reference is [***Foundations of Statistical Natural Language Processing***](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=3391) (1999) by Manning & Shutze. While comprehensive, relatively accessible and certainly a excellent reference, this may be overkill for a more casual introduction to the field.

You can maybe find some online courses such as **[Short course on Statistical Methods in NLP](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/users/resnik/nlstat_tutorial_summer1998/)**

And also, since you mentioned java, you can find a generic "toolbox" such as

- [**Weka**](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)
- [**Stanford Core NLP**](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml)
- [**openNLP**](http://incubator.apache.org/opennlp/)
- [**GATE**](http://gate.ac.uk/)

and start getting hands-on exposure to specific areas of NLP such as, say, POS Tagging or Entity Extraction.
Also worthy of mention, 'though it is related to a the Python-based NLTK, the [*Natural Language Processing with Python* online (and hardcopy) book](http://www.nltk.org/book) constitutes a very practical guide into common NLP tasks.

There is a bit of a catch-22 with getting one's feet wet with NLP:  it is a rather extensive field of study and practice.  It is rife with both scholarly research and time and industry tested practices and libraries.  Until one has a better grasp of the particular applications of NLP that are suitable for a given problem, one may waste a lot time poking technologies that are either immature or not well suited to the problems at hand.

Comment: Perfect answer. I'd highly recommend starting with NLTK (Python is super easy) so you can dip into a bunch of tools without needing to write a ton of code. When you step into the big java libraries (basically all the big stuff is written in java) there is a much more significant level of knowledge required. Also, as said, know your problem and that narrows down what nlp tools you use to solve it!